# how to pass array of struct to GPU?

Tags: c, cuda

i have this struct:

```
struct Node
{
     int *ptr;
     int k;   
}*d_ptr;
```

how can i declare an array of Node and pass it to the GPU? the problem is that i have to allocate memory for ptr first and then Node!

i have this till now:

```
int N=100;
int NumbOfNodes=5;
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_NodeArr, sizeof(Node)*NumbOfNodes);
for(int i=0;i<NumbOfNodes;i++)
    cudaMalloc((void **) d_NodeArr[i].Degree, sizeof(int)*N);
```

would it be faster if i allocated everything within a single array like this:

```
int N=100;
int NumbOfNodes=5;
int SIZE=(100*5)+5;//the +5 is for the k
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_ptr,sizeof(int)*SIZE);
```

Comment: Yes it will be faster to allocate everything in a single array. That is the common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just construct the structure on the host first.
That is, create the struct and then do a cudaMalloc for the int array.
Subsequently copy the struct itself from host to device.

This could help you along:
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=196084