# Malloc structure of array of structure of array in CUDA

Tags: cuda

How to properly malloc `struct A` with cuda?

```
struct B
{
    int* pointerToInt;
    int arraySize;
};
struct A
{
    B* pointerToB;
    int arraySize;
};
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135377/1231073) describes a way to allocate `structs` on device.

Answer (score 1):

If allocating on host memory, we can think of doing:

```
struct A* h_A;
h_A = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
h_A->arraySize = 10;
h_A->pointerToB = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct B));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    struct B h_B = (h_A->pointerToB)[i];
    h_B.arraySize = i + 5;
    h_B.pointerToInt = malloc((i + 5) * sizeof(int));
}
```

If we try to do similar stuff with `cudaMalloc`:

```
struct A* d_A;
cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeof(struct A));
d_A->arraySize = 10;                                       /*** error ***/
cudaMalloc(&(d_A->pointerToB), 10 * sizeof(struct B));     /*** error ***/
...
```

we'll encounter segmentation fault error because we are trying to dereference `d_A` which is allocated in device memory. We can't access device memory from host code using dereferencing operator.

One possible solution is to allocate device memory for `struct B` inside your device code. You can use `malloc` or `free` in device code to allocate device memory dynamically. See this section [B.20. Dynamic Global Memory Allocation and Operations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) on CUDA Programming Guide

Flattening your 2D array into 1D array might be a better solution.